# how i select specified selected rows of an excel sheet in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

function conv()
    {

```
    define('CSV_PATH','./uploads/');    #make a folder "csvfile" in your project root 
       $filename='./uploads/'.
       $csv_file = CSV_PATH ."ww.xls"; // Name of your CSV file
        $fp= fopen($csv_file, 'r');
```

i want to rows 19-22 and columns A-H from the excel sheet.please help

Answer (score 0):

I can not clearly see what you want to do but i believe i might be able to point you in the right direction... To read from the csv file, i dont think its a bad idea to use php's own fgetcsv() function... read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
Try this and improve on it:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
define('CSV_PATH','./uploads/');    #make a folder "csvfile" in your project root 
   $filename='./uploads/'.
   $csv_file = CSV_PATH ."ww.xls"; // Name of your CSV file

if (($fp= fopen($csv_file, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Sir if i want to Coulumn H values from the excel sheet how will i do ,i am using php-codeigniter

Comment: $row = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator($rownumber)->current();

$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo $cell->getValue();
}

Comment: @anju I can see you are using PHPExcel... I am not too familiar with it but i think you can get all the values in the csv by following this tutorial [link](https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/) after which you can do a var_dump on $arr_data so as to get the columns and values